# Merging 2 different SQL results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 different tables in MySQL/MariaDB that have different data about computer systems. There is a common field for `computer_name` but the contents of that field can be different for the same computer. In `TableA`, the `computer_name` could be 'hostname' while in `TableB` the `computer_name` could be 'hostname@dom1.domain'. I need to see `col1`, `col2`, `col3` from `TableA` and `col5`, `col6`, `col7` from `TableB` where the `computer_name` is something LIKE '%hostname%'.

Can this be done in pure SQL (selects or views or stored procedure) or can it be done in PHP?

TableA:

| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| tableA_id | int(10) unsigned | NO | PRI | NULL | auto_increment |
| computer_name | varchar(50) | NO |  | NULL |  |
| device_type | varchar(255) | NO |  | NULL |  |
| ip_address | varchar(150) | NO |  | NULL |  |
| os_type | varchar(50) | NO |  | NULL |  |
| laptop | varchar(255) | NO |  | NULL |  |
| operating_system | varchar(100) | NO |  | NULL |  |
| last_report_time | varchar(100) | NO |  | NULL |  |
| week_date | date | YES |  | NULL |  |
| month_id | int(10) unsigned | NO |  | NULL |  |
| year | int(10) unsigned | NO |  | NULL |  |
| create_date | datetime | NO |  | NULL |  |

TableB:

| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| tableb_id | int(10) unsigned | NO | PRI | NULL | auto_increment |
| computer_name | varchar(60) | NO |  | NULL |  |
| state | varchar(30) | NO |  | NULL |  |
| server_type | varchar(30) | NO |  | NULL |  |
| os_name | varchar(60) | YES |  | NULL |  |
| os_version | varchar(100) | YES |  | NULL |  |
| environment_status | varchar(60) | YES |  | NULL |  |
| mgmt_ip | text | YES |  | NULL |  |
| ad_domain | text | YES |  | NULL |  |
| owner | varchar(150) | YES |  | NULL |  |
| organization | varchar(150) | YES |  | NULL |  |
| dev_poc | varchar(255) | YES |  | NULL |  |
| tech_poc | varchar(255) | YES |  | NULL |  |
| application_desc | varchar(255) | YES |  | NULL |  |
| criticality | varchar(30) | YES |  | NULL |  |
| week_date | date | YES |  | NULL |  |
| month_id | int(10) | NO |  | NULL |  |
| year | int(10) | NO |  | NULL |  |
| create_date | datetime | NO |  | NULL |  |

Select from TableA;

```
|| *computer_name* || *ip_address* || *os_type* || *operating_system* || *last_report_time* || *create_date* ||
|| listserv-test || www.xxx.yyy.zzz || Unknown - Linux Red Hat Enterprise Server 7.9 || Linux Red Hat Enterprise Server 7.9 (3.10.0-1160.24.1.el7.x86_64) || Mon, 19 Apr 2021 10:51:23 +0000 || 2021-04-20 08:41:05 ||
|| listserv-test || www.xxx.yyy.zzz || Unknown - Linux Red Hat Enterprise Server 7.9 || Linux Red Hat Enterprise Server 7.9 (3.10.0-1160.21.1.el7.x86_64) || Fri, 09 Apr 2021 13:31:38 +0000 || 2021-04-12 14:55:37 ||
|| listserv-test || www.xxx.yyy.zzz || Unknown - Linux Amazon Linux 2 || Linux Amazon Linux 2 (4.14.225-169.362.amzn2.x86_64) || Mon, 05 Apr 2021 10:58:18 +0000 || 2021-04-08 13:53:14 ||
|| listserv.yyy.zzz || www.xxx.yyy.zzz || Unknown - Linux CentOS 6.10 || Linux CentOS 6.10 (2.6.32-754.35.1.el6.x86_64) || Mon, 19 Apr 2021 10:44:05 +0000 || 2021-04-20 08:41:05 ||
|| listserv.yyy.zzz || www.xxx.yyy.zzz || Unknown - Linux CentOS 6.10 || Linux CentOS 6.10 (2.6.32-754.35.1.el6.x86_64) || Mon, 12 Apr 2021 10:44:52 +0000 || 2021-04-12 14:55:37 ||
|| listserv.yyy.zzz || www.xxx.yyy.zzz || Unknown - Linux CentOS 6.10 || Linux CentOS 6.10 (2.6.32-754.35.1.el6.x86_64) || Mon, 05 Apr 2021 10:59:32 +0000 || 2021-04-08 13:53:14 ||
```

Select from TableB

```
|| *computer_name* || *state* || *os_name* || *os_version* || *owner*     || *organization* || *dev_poc* || *tech_poc* || *application_desc* ||
|| AVALISTSERVMSGPR02 || Installed ||  || Linux Amazon Linux 2 (4.14.219-161.340.amzn2.x86_64) ||  ||  ||  ||  ||  ||
|| LISTSERV || Installed || Linux CentOS || Linux CentOS 6.10 (2.6.32-754.11.1.el6.x86_64) || ||  ||  ||  || Messaging ||
|| LISTSERV.yyy.zzz || Installed || Linux CentOS || Linux CentOS 6.10 (2.6.32-754.18.2.el6.x86_64) ||  ||  ||  ||  ||  ||
```

Comment: It can be done in either or both

Comment: Now seriously, show us the schema for both these tables, an example of the data in both showing these various situations. You have to work a little in order for us to help

Comment: Recommended reading: [creating a minimal, reproducible example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `join` like this:

```
select . . .
from a join
     b
     on a.computer_name = substring_index(b.computer_name, '@', 1);
```